# Active Directory Import in Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, user-profile

I am new to Sharepoint 2013 and started working on Sharepoint 2013 Foundation version. I have a requirement that suggest to Import or Synchronize Active Directory users with Sharepoint user profiles. 
Before getting more into it, is it possible to Import AD user profile in Sharepoint Foundation 2013 through Central Administration? Or it can be done only in Server edition?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SharePoint 2016 there are no Foundation only version to be installed, but on 2013 SharePoint Foundation is still available. You can use [Active Directory import](https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/) with either Foundation, Standard or Enterprise edition.

More to read:

- [SharePoint 2013 feature comparison chart all editions](https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/)
- [Configure profile synchronization by using SharePoint Active Directory Import in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx)

To check your version, brows to `http://CentralAdminURL:port/_admin/Conversion.aspx` and see if you have Enterprise or Standard

[image]

Comment: Any workaround available in Foundation for this?

Comment: I do not have Standard or Enterprise Edition, I am working on Sp 2013 Foundation version only. Is there any workaround/trick possible for AD User Import in Foundation version?

Comment: I got your point but in my view it is showing "Current License         <blank>"

Comment: "*In SharePoint 2013 there are no Foundation only version....*" - Are you sure you meant 2013 and not 2016? [Because this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35488). They removed foundation from 2016.

Comment: @Abhitalks You're absolutely right. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: "You can use Active Directory import with either Foundation, Standard or Enterprise edition." Can u suggest how to do that in Foundation 2013 ? Without Custom code suggested in "http://www.macaalay.com/2014/03/27/synchronize-active-directory-information-with-sharepoint-foundation-2013-user-profiles/".

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one ([Synchronize Active Directory Information with Sharepoint Foundation 2013 User Profiles](http://www.macaalay.com/2014/03/27/synchronize-active-directory-information-with-sharepoint-foundation-2013-user-profiles/)) to import you AD user to SharePoint Foundation 2013 User Profiles

Comment: I am trying this, this seems a workaround

Comment: Yes, because the functionality to import users from active directory does not exist in sharepoint 2013 foundation